# Set item price added to cart

Tags: magento2, php, price, tax, discount

I tried to change the `price, tax and discount` of each product added to cart.
I could change the price of each item with observer and code below, but i cant change the discount and tax. How can i change it?

Observer :

```
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to change discount and tax?

Comment: I count the price, tax, and discount by my own calculation in service, so i need to change them.

Comment: Shouldn't change the tax. It does not make sense. We should create the tax rules. I think the same solution for the discount. We should change total.

Comment: How can i change the total? I already tried to change the total with `$quote->setDiscountAmount(1);` but it's nor work.